# Git pull in a Linux environment changes the owner of the files

Tags: git, chown

Why will every time I execute a `git pull` on my live server, the owner of the files be changed? I keep on manually doing a `chown john:john index.php`.

What do I need to change so that, when I do a `git pull`, the owner of the files will be automatically be or stay `john`?

Comment: Is `john` the owner of the current directory?

Comment: Yes, john is the owner of the directory :)

Comment: Which user running `git pull`?

Comment: @Gnouc root user, I am logged in in our live server via SSH as root user :)

Answer (score 14):

When you use `git pull` (which is equivalent to `git fetch; git merge`), git create new files and does not care about previous ownership (git does not store that information).

There is different solution to solve this. The easier is probably to add a `post-update` hooks (in your `.git/hooks` directory) to automatically call `chown john:john . -R` after merge/pull  ([see that SO solution for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613545/how-to-control-ownership-of-files-auto-pushed-to-a-git-target-repo-by-commit-hoo)).

Alternate solutions are:

- Run `git pull` as the john user instead of root (that will require write permissions to john for .git directory).
- Create a hook to make the deployment, which will either use john as user, either do the chown after update (so you will have to do `git pull` inside the `post-receive` hook of the bare repo).

In linux, it might be another solution with `setuid` / `setgid`

Comment: What if you do `git fetch` as root and then `git merge` as user john?  Will john still need write permissions for `.git` directory?

Comment: Yes, most of times. `git fetch` as root, new files in .git/objects` might have root as owner. `git merge` as user john will (most of time) try to overwrite at least `.git/index` and `.git/HEAD` (which might be deleted/created at each change I suppose), and write some files in `.git/objects/`. + any new files in your working directory.

Maybe there is exceptions with fast forward merge for example.

Comment: "git will update files without changing owner" not according to my tests: ```anocube@5153F344:~/terminal/conf/ubuntu $ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     michael  956 Mar 10 11:56 terminal_sudoers
michael@5153F344:~/terminal/conf/ubuntu $ git pull
Updating 77b4d18..b281757
Fast-forward
 conf/ubuntu/terminal_sudoers | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
michael@5153F344:~/terminal/conf/ubuntu $ ll
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 michael michael 1001 Mar 10 11:57 terminal_sudoers
michael@5153F344:~/terminal/conf/ubuntu $ 
``` Here root:michael changes to michael:michael

Comment: @run_the_race I'm pretty sure I tested before writing the answer, but it seems you're right. So maybe in 2015 it wasn't the case (or maybe I simply am wrong ^^). Thanks for the report, so I edited the answer